# VTK Marching Cubes from vtkImageReader2

Tags: c++, vtk

I have encountered problems of loading image stack into vtkImageReader2 in order to perform surface extraction using vtkMarchingCubes.

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageReader2> reader = vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageReader2>::New();

    reader->SetFilePrefix("C:\\");
    reader->SetFilePattern("%d.png");
    reader->SetDataExtent(0,556,0,613,0,200);
    reader->SetDataSpacing(1,1,1);
    reader->SetDataOrigin(0,0,0);
    reader->SetDataByteOrderToLittleEndian();
    reader->SetDataScalarTypeToUnsignedShort();
    reader->Update();
    reader->UpdateWholeExtent();
```

FYI, the image dataset is 556x614x201 in dimension.

The image file name is for example like below:

```
 0.png
 1.png
 2.png and till 200.png
```

It complains about  `Initialize: Could not open file (randomnumber).png`.
The reader seems cannot find the file with the prefix and pattern given.

However, after i loaded the image successfully using vtkstringarray by manually setting the image path and its file name, i encountered problem of `Cannot contour data of dimension != 3`

Comment: what is the code for loading the image successfully? From your wording it seems that you have loaded 1 image (dimension = 2), I think you should use  SetFileNames (vtkStringArray *). Have you tried also vtkPNGreader? If you haven't seen yet, have a look at http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/How-read-stack-of-TIF-images-tp1241362p1241363.html . For the first snippet, the random slice that cannot be read is <200? have you checked it for any reason the file is malformed? Or if your filename is actually 002.png and not 2.png?

Comment: Hi, i have used SetFileNames using VTKStringArray to pinpoint the exact filenames of those 201 slices of image. However, after that i will encounter the problem of cannot contour data of dimension !=3. i havent used VTKPNGreader though.. Thanks a lot for your suggestion.

Comment: FYI, i have successfully loaded the image by convert it to RAW file before loading it using vtkImageReader2. Thanks a lot lib